# Using pipes in re.split results in extra split occuring

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string by `|INDEX|` and `/`.

`re.split` can handle multiple separator and uses pipes to separate each separator, so they need to be escaped.

I tried separating with:

```
a = 'Tokenized/0003036v1|INDEX|3847.story.json'
re.split( r"/|\|INDEX|\|"  , a)
```

However, this resulted in an extra, empty split:

```
['Tokenized', '0003036v1', '', '3847.story.json']
```

Why are there 4 items in the list with an empty item, instead of three?

Comment: there is an extra `|` symbol after X, that is the reason you are facing empty string. to know the result step by step pass in the max split argument, you can understand the split results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your regex, with an extra `|` before the closing `\|` for `|INDEX|`, so the string is being split on `|INDEX` and `|`, resulting in the empty string between them. Change the regex to this:

```
re.split( r"/|\|INDEX\|"  , a)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
re.split( r"/|\|INDEX|\|"  , a)
```

use this

```
re.split( r"/|\|INDEX\|"  , a)

# splitting based on maxsplit argument to know where the problem is present
>>> re.split( r"/|\|INDEX|\|"  , a,1)
['Tokenized', '0003036v1|INDEX|3847.story.json']
>>> re.split( r"/|\|INDEX|\|"  , a,2)
['Tokenized', '0003036v1', '|3847.story.json']
>>> re.split( r"/|\|INDEX|\|"  , a,3)
['Tokenized', '0003036v1', '', '3847.story.json']
>>> re.split( r"/|\|INDEX\|"  , a)
['Tokenized', '0003036v1', '3847.story.json']
```